# Protocol handler broken for protected mode in office insider fast build

Tags: ms-word, office-js, officedev

We're developing Add-ins for Office. For some scenario's we use the protocol handler for Word.
When a file is originating from the a location that triggers the "Protected View", the documents opens with the yellow bar where you can enable editing of the document. When I click "**enable editing**" a message is shown "**A file error has occurred.**"
This functionality has worked for a long time and seems to be broken since the last update of Word: Office Insider - Version 1802 Build 9026.2006

I can uncheck the "Enable Protected view for...." options in the trust center and then it works, so the document itself is fine. But of course this is a work around.

So my question is, can anybody reproduce this and/or can someone from Microsoft address this so it's fixed in the next build.

Thanx Chris

Comment: thanks for reporting this. I was able to repro this issue today and have escalated it to the appropriate engineering team here at Microsoft.